# What is the easiest/most useful way to inspect an environment in R?

Tags: r, environment, inspect

I am using different environments to save masses of data, something like this for many environments:

```
myEnv <- new.env()
myEnv$data1 <- my.data.table1
myEnv$data2 <- my.data.table2
save(myEnv, file = "myEnv.rda")
```

Now later on I load the `.rda` file that I need and I would like to see what is contained within it, if possible a few levels deep - that is to get an overview of both `data1` and `data2` that are saved within it.

Using `str(myEnv)`simply tells me it is an environment:

```
> str(myEnv)
<environment: 0x7f9869af1f18>
```

This kind of reminds me of the way `yield` and **iterators** work in Python.

I can do `ls(myEnv)` to see that there are objects *data1* and *data2*, then I can do `str(myEnv$data1)` to see more about that object.

I am just wondering if there isn't a smarter and/or faster way to get an overview of the contents of an environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ls.str()`:

```
myEnv <- new.env()
myEnv$data1 <- data.frame()
myEnv$data1 <- data.frame()
ls.str(myEnv)
#> data1 : 'data.frame':    0 obs. of  0 variables
#> data2 : 'data.frame':    0 obs. of  0 variables
```

Also `is()` or `class()` may be helpful:

```
lapply(myEnv, class)
#> $data1
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> $data2
#> [1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: Thanks, both suggestions are useful! For my purposes I found `lapply(myEnv, ls)` to be most useful, with `ls.str(myEnv)` going a bit deeper as necessary.

Comment: @DexterMorgan consider adding the green check if this is the most useful answer.